# Missing parts of the model when importing as Collada (DAE)

Tags: import, collada

I use Collada files from SketchUp.

When I import them into Blender some times import goes as intented but sometimes it imports only part of it.

Here is for example you can see this chair.
**The right one is imported as Collada (DAE), and the left one is the same .DAE file, but I put it trough online mesh converter and imported as OBJ.**

Why can it be and how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: try importing into .obj,
it is much better than .dae
besides not disturbing the vertices

Comment: Rafael, please, read carefully.
I already wrote in the question about .obj

I need to import .dae

Comment: [Related](https://developer.blender.org/T34552). I've stumbled across this problem too. Seems like conversion is the only solution so far.